# NavBar with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have an unordered list of links in XHTML. I want to make a horizontal nav bar for my webpage using CSS2.1. However, when I try to make the positioning of the nav bar absolute, all the links stack on top of each other so I can't see them. So I made the positioning relative. When I shrink the width of the browser window, everything resizes as it should, but I don't want the nav bar to resize, because the links are stacking underneath each other which is not what I want. Just wondered if there is an easier way and if I'm doing anything wrong as regards the resizing conundrum. Thanks

XHTML

```
<div class="box" id="box1">
<h1>Welcome</h1>


<ul class="navlist" id="navbar">
 <li><a href="#intro">Intro</a></li>
 <li><a href="#howto">HowTo</a></li>
 <li><a href="#why">But Why?</a></li>
 <li><a href="#faq">FAQs</a>
    <ul class="navlist" id="sublist">
    <li><a href="#letters">alphabet</a></li>
    <li><a href="#numbers">digits</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.navlist li{

    position:relative;


    top: -117px;
    left:25em; 


    list-style-type:none;
    padding-left:0;
    margin-left:0;
    display: inline;
}

ul.navlist a{
    color: #333;
    padding-right: 3px;
    padding-left: 3px;
    margin-right: 2px;
    text-decoration: none;


}

#navbar li ul{

    position: absolute;
    width: 15em;
    left: -899em;   
}

#navbar li:hover ul {
    left: -420px; 
    top: 140px;
    }
```

Comment: You have `top: -117px;` listed, which is putting your links 117 pixels above the top of your viewport. Remove the negative sign.

Comment: I know it looks like it should'nt work with the minus sign but the -117 pixels has the nav bar in exactly the right place... its just when I resize my browser window, the links cascade on top of each other.. The position of the links is fine I just don't want them to resize

Comment: This is what your code outputs with the -117px: http://jsfiddle.net/33URZ/

Comment: its -117 because I have other code above it in the HTML.. im moving the list up above everything else... the position of the nav bar is fine.. thats all working.. its just that when I resize the window... the nav bar stays in exactly the same place, and thus ends up off screen, I want the nav bar to move left relative to the left hand side of my browser as I close it in